# Unable to build the Test Project that used Google test

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, googletest

I built the google test project.

I added the include directories in `General -> Addition Include Directories.`
I added the library directory to the `Linker -> Additional Library directories`
I added gtest_maind.lib and gtestd.lib to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

I followed instructions in an another chain to change the `Code Generation -> Runtime Library to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`

*Note: I am using Visual Studio 2010*

In spite of doing all the above I still get the following link error

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall 
Utility::~Utility(void)" (??1Utility@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: virtual
void __thiscall UtiltyTest_test1_Test::TestBody(void)" (?
TestBody@UtiltyTest_test1_Test@@EAEXXZ) C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Visual Studio 
2010\Projects\Calc\CalTest\UtilityTest.obj
```

Am I missing something here. Could someone help me solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to test any .c files?
Because if you are you should try this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus 
  extern "C" {
#endif
    void cFunctionCalledFromCppFile();
#ifdef __cplusplus 
  }
#endif
```

Comment: No I am using only .cpp files